# How can I send both file and json data in a single request in Django using Requests library on the client side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, api

I need to send json data and file to my api in django. In the client side i use requests and i will share that code below. I tried this code but it gave "django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream". Hope you can help.

client side:

```
import requests
my_json={
#some json data
}
file = {"file": open("sample.txt", "rb")}
response = requests.post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/API/upload-file", data=my_json, files=file
)
print(response.text)
```

endpoint in views.py

```
def get_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        uploaded_file = request.FILES["file"]
        json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        print(json_data)
        print(uploaded_file.filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches i found out the solution. In client side sending json using data key of requests is essential. If you try to send it using json key you will get TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str. The working code in server side is given below:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class FileUploadView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        file = request.FILES.get("file")
        print("Uploaded file: " + file._get_name())
        json_data = {k: v for k, v in request.data.dict().items() if k != "file"}
        print(json_data)
```

In my case I only needed a specific key pair from json so instead of converting i just simply used `request.data.get("key_value")`.